# A better database system for log and retrieve

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I just got the requirements for a new task.

There is this service that updates data in one system (who comes as CSV file) from another (SQL server): the task requires me to store a serialized version of each record we copy, with a checksum and  a timestamp. There will be no updates, just inserts and retrievals based on timestamps and checksums. There can be also SELECTS based on the contents of the serialization. The max quantity of data we are going store is in the order of N*1m; I hardly see in the system more than a few million rows. I see it growing from few hundreds to few thousands rows max a day for the next 3 years, then the system will be dismissed.

My team is expert with MS SQL SERVER, but I wonder if there is any better engine (Kafka, Cassandra, etc) to support this kind of scenario. Any advice/idea? What would be the benefits to justify the effort of teaching/promoting in our team? Please note also that we primarily work in C#, so an easy way to interface with it should be favorable.

I am not DBA so I might overlook some details. In case just let me know and I will clarify.
Thank you

Comment: So you already have data in ms sql server that's being copied from one server to another via a service (like a poor mans replication?) and you just want to store the log of the copied records to see when it was moved?

Comment: Data does not come from a SQL database: the source is CSV file. The destination system will only use some of the information available in the CSV file to update records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main use case is perfectly suited to a relational database, and since you have SQL Server experience that seems like an obvious choice. There aren't any obvious benefits to searching for a new database product based on what you've told us.

With the small size you mentioned, you may even be able to get away with using [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) (free version, up to 10GB per database) and skip out on the cost of licensing it. There are a few feature differences, but it's worth looking into from what you've said so far as its perfect for this quick, one-off type use cases.

Since it doesn't have a long life ahead of it, this makes the free version an even more attractive option. Then again, it's sort of dangerous to expect something to be decommissioned on time... :)

Comment: thanks, actually the express version could be a good alternative as we are running short of enterprise licenses. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, any relational DB will do just fine at this task. Both requirements for functionality and indicated size are well within the capabilities of just about relational DB available today. Since you mention being a shop with SQL Server expertise, I would recommend sticking with what you know. While it's always fun to experiment with new technologies, if you stray from what you know, you'll create a dependency on a technology that is not part of your shop's expertise.

On the flip side, if your shop is willing and able to make Open Source a permanent part of your technology repertoire (a good idea, btw) then and only then would it be reasonable to bring in a technology that you're currently unfamiliar with, such as MySQL or one of the NoSQL databases.